# Why position: relative without z-index creates a new stacking context?

Tags: css

From this [article](https://tiffanybbrown.com/2015/09/css-stacking-contexts-wtf/index.html):

> Two elements with the same stack level are layered based on their source order. Successive elements stack on top of their predecessors.

And from [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context):

> A stacking context is formed, anywhere in the document, by any element in the following scenarios: ... 2. Element with a position value "absolute" or "relative" **and z-index value other than "auto".**

Now please look at this piece of code:

```css
.c1 {
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
}


.c2 {
   background: green;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  Why I'm visible?
</div> 

<div class="c2">&nbsp;</div>
```

As follows from two previous quotes, `div.c1` shouldn't create a new stacking context, because it doesn't have `z-index`. Therefore, `div.c1` and `div.c2` are in `<html>` stacking context, and should be rendered in order. But why `div.c2` is rendered **under** `div.c1`?

Comment: Does `position:relative` not take it out of the normal flow of the document?

Comment: @morne from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position): 
*relative*: The element **is positioned according to the normal flow** of the document, and then offset relative to itself based on the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

Comment: position: relative does not change the flow order of the element, but changes the element position relative to the normal flow position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the accepted answer is incorrect - `top`, `left`, `bottom` and `right` have nothing to do with this. If you remove the `top` and add a negative `margin-bottom`, you'll see it still gets drawn on top.

```css
.c1 {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}


.c2 {
   background: green;
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  Why I'm visible?
</div> 

<div class="c2">&nbsp;</div>
```

Took me a while to figure out what was actually going on here, but the important concepts are *stack level* and *stacking contexts*. Stack level is essentially determined by `z-index`, and elements with `z-index: auto` (which is the default for `z-index`) have stack level 0. The reason the relatively positioned is drawn on top of the statically positioned one is because the spec simply defines the painting order that way; positioned elements with stack level 0 get drawn *after* non-positioned elements. [This section](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index) of the spec states that within each stacking context, the order of painting is

> 1. the background and borders of the element forming the stacking context.
> 2. the child stacking contexts with negative stack levels (most negative first).
> 3. the in-flow, non-inline-level, non-positioned descendants.
>    the non-positioned floats.
> 4. the in-flow, inline-level, non-positioned descendants, including inline tables and inline blocks.
> 5. the child stacking contexts with stack level 0 and the positioned descendants with stack level 0.
> 6. the child stacking contexts with positive stack levels (least positive first).

I'll now demonstrate the difference between a relatively positioned element that does create a stacking context and one that doesn't.

```js
const blueBox = document.querySelector('#blue-box');
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const opacity1 = document.querySelector('#opacity-1');
const opacityNot1 = document.querySelector('#opacity-not-1');

let opacity = 1;

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  if(opacity == 1){
    opacity = .9;
    opacity1.hidden = true;
    opacityNot1.hidden = false;
  }
  else {
    opacity = 1;
    opacity1.hidden = false;
    opacityNot1.hidden = true;
  }
  blueBox.style.opacity = opacity;
})
```

```css
#blue-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
}

#yellow-box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
  top: 75px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: yellow;
}

#red-box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="blue-box" style="opacity: 1">
  <div id="yellow-box"></div>
</div>

<div id="red-box"></div>

<button>Toggle opacity for blue box</button>
<p id="opacity-1">Blue box has <code>opacity: 1;</code> (so does NOT create a new stacking context)</p>
<p id="opacity-not-1" hidden>Blue box has <code>opacity: .9;</code> (so it creates a new stacking context)</p>
```

There are three boxes here; all are relatively positioned, the yellow box creates a new stacking context with stack level 1 as defined by its `z-index`. The button toggles whether or not the blue box creates a stacking context (using `opacity` - if `opacity` is less than one, the element creates a new stacking context).

Now, let's see what happens in either state. Let's first look at what happens when the blue box does NOT create a new stacking context.

All three boxes simply get drawn according to the order listed above. That is, the blue and red boxes are both in category 5 as elements that are positioned with stack level 0. The yellow box is positioned with stack level 1 so gets painted on top.

Now, we toggle the blue box's opacity to be 0.9, making it create a new stacking context. What happens now?

Well, now the blue box triggers the above painting order by itself, i.e. the CSS engine now paints all of the blue boxes' children when it draws the blue box. Essentially, it will draw the blue box *and its stacking context* (so including the yellow box) first, and then it draws the red box (which as a result goes on top of the yellow box).

---

TLDR; elements with `position: relative` do not create a new stacking context, but get drawn on top of non-positioned elements (i.e. elements with `position: static`) either way because they are positioned elements.

Answer (score 1):

Relative positioning introduces the ability to use z-index on that element, which doesn't really work with statically positioned elements. So, even if you ***don't*** set a z-index value, this element will now appear ***on top*** of any other statically positioned element.

Also If you set ***position: relative;*** on an element but no other positioning attributes (top, left, bottom or right), it will have no effect on it's positioning at all, it will be exactly as it would be if you left it as ***position: static***; But if you ***do*** give it some other positioning attribute, say as per your example, top: 50px;, it will shift its position 50 pixels down from where it would normally be.

This is why your .c1 is "stacked" over .c2

Comment: Does this mean that MDN article is not accurate? They say nothing about this

Answer (score 1):

position: relative means that the elements are rendered in the normal flow as they should and then the offset is calculated relative to its own position.So without the offset(which you have provided), the order should be:render c1 first and then render c2 below it(not over it),as both of them are block elements.In the above code you have provided an offset of 10px to c1,so it got displaced 10px downwards and got overlapped with c2.

Comment: Seems like this is correct answer: position: relative doesn't create a new stacking context in this case. c1 is just getting an offset  after c2 is rendered. So the process is: 1) render c1 2) render c2 3) rerender c1 with an offset

Comment: This answer is not correct - see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69572903/3546284)

Answer (score 0):

here the c1 has got the stacking context since it has position:relative in it, so if you give position absolute to c2 then both the divs will be at same level. Then it will be layered on the source order.

```css
.c1 {
  position:relative;
  background:blue;
  top: 50px;
}


.c2 {
  position:absolute;
   background: green;
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="c1">
  I'm visible?
</div> 

<div class="c2">&nbsp;</div>
```

Comment: It doesn't get stacking context, because it doesn't have `z-index`

Comment: @mqklin position also influences the stacking along with floating and z-index.

Comment: @monssef To form a context, element should have a position value "absolute" or "relative" **and** z-index value other than "auto" (according to MDN article). So there is **and**, not _or_.